# Pause on Mouse Hover not Working on JCarousel

Tags: jquery, hover, jcarousel

I have been to a lot of answers but not one of it has answered my problem. I have this JCarousel, autoscroll. I want it to stop on hover, what do I need to add up in my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 1,
        wrap: 'circular',
        vertical: true,
        animation: 3500,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        scroll:1,
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for the resoudere promeble of how to make  Pause on Mouse Hover working on JCarousel

step : 1 make this function in the root  of our safe ( file.js) .

```
 function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};
```

step 2: make this function in ready function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//exemple
 jQuery('#carosule ul').jcarousel({
     scroll:1,
     visible:4,
     wrap:"circular",
     animation:300,
     auto:1,
     hoverPause: true,
     width: 160,
     initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the your initialization: `initCallback(carousel)`

```
carousel.clip.hover(function() {
    carousel.stopAuto();
}, function() {
    carousel.startAuto();
});
```

---

This has been even mentioned in a [bug](http://drupal.org/node/677754) in jCarousel.

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};
```

Comment: can you edit the code I provided and include this one? I'm a newbie of this so I don't know where to insert it. Sorry.

Comment: Nopes. It is not in your code. You need to edit the plugin file.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer to stay current.

See https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/568 for the correct answer:

```
$('.jcarousel').hover(function() {
    $(this).jcarouselAutoscroll('stop');
}, function() {
    $(this).jcarouselAutoscroll('start');
});
```